# for Loop NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

So I am looping down using NSFetchedResultsController, however, the title remains the same but everything else is where it needs to be.

```
for (Objective * objs in self.fetchedResultsControllerObj.fetchedObjects) {
    self.fetchedResultsControllerStrats = [self fetchedResultsControllerStrat:objs.sexfluence_user_objectives_id];
  for (Stratagy * strats in self.fetchedResultsControllerStrats.fetchedObjects) {
    RADataObject *stratagies = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:strats.sexfluence_user_stratagy_title children:nil];
    [stratagiesobjects addObject:stratagies];
  }
    RADataObject *objectives = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:objs.sexfluence_user_objectives_title children:stratagiesobjects];
    [objectivesobjects addObject:objectives];
}
```

This produces this.[image]
as you can see the title: "Take more time to develop" is listed in all 3 titles.
Please let me know what I am missing or assist me to complete this code block.

Comment: Is there a relationship between `Objective` and `Stratagy`? I mean is there one defined in your core data model?

Comment: Yes, that relationship exists. I have tried removing it as well.

Comment: Why would you want to remove it? You should use it instead of the second fetch results controller.

Comment: I tried to remove it play around with it, and when i still got the same results, I posted my messgage here.